# Почему $field .= $val['name']... ?

Tags: php

Помогите разобрать следующий PHP Function код, например, почему это так:

```
$field .= $val['name']."='".mysql_real_escape_string($val['val'])."',";
```

и т.п.

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 * @param string $tblName имя таблицы куда вставляем данные
 * @param array $fields
 * многомерный массив полей имеющий вид
 *  array(array('name'=>'имя поля в базе','val'=>'значение'),
 *  array('name'=>'имя поля2 в базе','val'=>'значение2'))
 */

function Add($tblName,$fields)
{
    if(is_array($fields))
    {
        foreach ($fields as $val) $field .= $val['name']."='".mysql_real_escape_string($val['val'])."',";
        $field = substr($field,0,-1);
        if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tblName SET $field ;"))
        {
            $companyId = mysql_insert_id();
            return $companyId;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else return false;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, в описании функции уже все написано.
Допустим мы передаем в функцию массив:

```
array(array('name'=>'field1','val'=>'5'),array('name'=>'field2','val'=>'33'))
```

В функции в цикле мы обходим этот массив

```
foreach ($fields as $val) 
$field .= $val['name']."='".mysql_real_escape_string($val['val'])."',";
```

В конце мы получим в переменной $field строку типа

```
"field1='5',field2='33'"
```

и следующей строкой мы выполним INSERT в базу

```
INSERT INTO $tblName SET field1='5',field2='33' ;
```

Функция mysql_insert_id() вернет id последней вставленной записи, т.е. результатом работы функции будет id строки которую мы проинсертили или false во всех остальных случаях.